# How to launch a package after its been installed in CQ

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

I'm working with a ZIP file that was given to me. When extracted, the contents of the zip file are as follows:

```
~/java/aem/Demo-Combined $ tree
.
├── META-INF
│   └── vault
│       ├── config.xml
│       ├── definition
│       │   ├── thumbnail
│       │   │   ├── file
│       │   │   └── file.dir
│       │   └── thumbnail.png
│       ├── filter.xml
│       ├── nodetypes.cnd
│       └── properties.xml
└── jcr_root
    ├── apps
    │   └── proxy
    │       └── install
    │           └── proxy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    └── etc
        └── packages
            └── demo-team
                ├── Users-1.0.1.zip
                ├── Users-1.0.1.zip.dir
                │   └── _jcr_content
                │       └── _vlt_definition
                │           ├── thumbnail
                │           │   ├── file
                │           │   └── file.dir
                │           └── thumbnail.png
                ├── Workflow-1.0.1.zip
                └── Workflow-1.0.1.zip.dir
                    └── _jcr_content
                        └── _vlt_definition
                            ├── thumbnail
                            │   ├── file
                            │   └── file.dir
                            └── thumbnail.png
```

When I upload and install this package to `http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/index.jsp` Three separate packages get installed

1. Workflow-1.0.1.zip
2. Users-1.0.1.zip
3. Demo-Combined.zip

Filters for each one are as follows:

**Workflow**

```
Filters:    /etc/workflow/scripts/delta
/etc/workflow/models/delta
/etc/workflow/launcher/config/delta-start-approval
/etc/taskmanagement/tasks/2013-02-28/Delta
```

**Users**

```
Filters:    /home/groups/delta
/home/users/delta
```

**Demo-Combined**

```
Filters:    /etc/packages/demo-team/Users-1.0.1.zip
/etc/packages/demo-team/Website-2.0.4.zip
/etc/packages/demo-team/Workflow-1.0.1.zip
/apps/proxy
```

**Questions**

Everything installs fine but I don't know how to launch this so that I can test it in my browser.

When I go to `http://localhost:4502/siteadmin` I don't see it in the left navigation. How can I launch this in my browser so that I may begin testing/playing around with it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website section basically shows the nodes below /content.

Those packages contain no content, so nothing will appear there. It seems they contain a bundle, some workflows and a test users.

I guess what you want is to test a workflow. You can do that in any page, even a geometrixx one

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I'm new to AEM. Can you please tell me how I can test this workflow in geometrixx?

Comment: the CQ5 docs are normally your best source http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/workflows/wf-using.htm